# Issues Connecting Flask app with Flask-Socket.io

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a flask app and I am trying to get flask-socket.io to work. The app name is rocket_launcher.

rocket_launcher/**init**.py has

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    # other app creation stuff

#socketio = SocketIO(create_app(),logger=True, engineio_logger=True)   
socketio = SocketIO(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)   

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(data):
    logger.debug('received message: ' + data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

My shell script (run.sh) to run my app is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=rocket_launcher
export FLASK_DEBUG=True
#python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
flask --app rocket_launcher run --host=0.0.0.0
```

The javascript I load with the starting page:

```
var socket = io()
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('my_event', {data:"I\'m connected!"});
});
```

When the app starts, it works (except the socketio stuff). For output, I get:

```
(rocket_launcher_flask) mark@piranha:~/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask$ ./run.sh 
sys.path=['/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin/python', '/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher', '/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask', '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
2023-09-07:22:44:47,636 DEBUG    [expansion_board_1.py:25] LHF init
2023-09-07:22:44:47,636 DEBUG    [expansion_board_1.py:30] Launcher_Hardware_Factory create_object
2023-09-07:22:44:47,637 DEBUG    [expansion_board_1.py:51] No hardware
No hardware
2023-09-07:22:44:47,637 INFO     [fsm.py:19] fsm __init__
started
2023-09-07:22:44:47,640 DEBUG    [model.py:16] started
 * Serving Flask app 'rocket_launcher'
 * Debug mode: on
2023-09-07:22:44:47,642 INFO     [_internal.py:187] WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.50.132:5000
2023-09-07:22:44:47,643 INFO     [_internal.py:187] Press CTRL+C to quit
2023-09-07:22:44:47,643 INFO     [_internal.py:187]  * Restarting with stat
sys.path=['/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin/python', '/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher', '/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask', '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
2023-09-07:22:44:48,024 DEBUG    [expansion_board_1.py:25] LHF init
2023-09-07:22:44:48,024 DEBUG    [expansion_board_1.py:30] Launcher_Hardware_Factory create_object
2023-09-07:22:44:48,025 DEBUG    [expansion_board_1.py:51] No hardware
No hardware
2023-09-07:22:44:48,025 INFO     [fsm.py:19] fsm __init__
started
2023-09-07:22:44:48,028 DEBUG    [model.py:16] started
2023-09-07:22:44:48,030 WARNING  [_internal.py:187]  * Debugger is active!
2023-09-07:22:44:48,030 INFO     [_internal.py:187]  * Debugger PIN: 751-117-059
2023-09-07:22:44:49,948 INFO     [_internal.py:187] 192.168.50.132 - - [07/Sep/2023 22:44:49] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfpKbGI HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2023-09-07:22:44:55,953 INFO     [_internal.py:187] 192.168.50.132 - - [07/Sep/2023 22:44:55] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfpKckA HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2023-09-07:22:45:01,968 INFO     [_internal.py:187] 192.168.50.132 - - [07/Sep/2023 22:45:01] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfpKeC9 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2023-09-07:22:45:07,982 INFO     [_internal.py:187] 192.168.50.132 - - [07/Sep/2023 22:45:07] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfpKfg7 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2023-09-07:22:45:14,087 INFO     [_internal.py:187] 192.168.50.132 - - [07/Sep/2023 22:45:14] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfpKh9X HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2023-09-07:22:45:20,101 INFO     [_internal.py:187] 192.168.50.132 - - [07/Sep/2023 22:45:20] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfpKidU HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I also do not get any socket.io logging or error messages. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you work with the Flask-SocketIO documentation and the provided examples, as there are a couple of things you are missing.

First of all, the `SocketIO()` class needs to be initialized with your `app` instance. You should move it inside your `create_app()` function:

```py
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    socketio.init_app(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)   

    # other app creation stuff
    return app
```

Next, you have to use the `socketio.run()` method to run the server, not `flask run`. One way to do this is to remove the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block from `rocket_launcher/__init__.py` and put it in a top-level `run.py` file, for example like this:

```py
from rocket_launcher import create_app, socketio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

To start the server, then you start `run.py` as a regular script:

```bash
python run.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! With your changes, I got the message (I'm connected), and now there are PING and PONG packets going back and forth from the server to the client. I only found one reference to socketio.init_app in the documentation, buried in a comment the API Reference. I was just following the Getting Started Guide, which didn't quite match how I created my Flask app, per that Getting Started Guide. Thanks again for your help!!!